# Codeigniter Datatable Server Side library with where condition is not working

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatables, server-side

I am Making A serverside library for Codeigniter serverside library I want to add a where condition Like bellow inside `__construct` function but how I can implement in to query ?

```
$this->where = (array_key_exists('where', $params) === TRUE && (is_array($params['where']) === TRUE || is_string($params['where']) === TRUE)) ? $params['where'] : [];
```

**The Library**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Serverside
{

    private $table;
    private $column_order;
    private $column_search;
    private $order;
    private $where;
    private $CI;

    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Constructor
     * @param array $params Initialization parameters
     * @return  void
     */
    function __construct( array $params ) {

        //set codeigniter instance
        $this->CI = & get_instance();

        // Set table name
        $this->table = (array_key_exists('table', $params) === TRUE && is_string($params['table']) === TRUE) ? $params['table'] : '';

        // Set table column fields to display
        $this->column_order = (array_key_exists('column_order', $params) === TRUE && is_array($params['column_order']) === TRUE) ? $params['column_order'] : [];

        // Set searchable column fields
        $this->column_search = (array_key_exists('column_search', $params) === TRUE && (is_array($params['column_search']) === TRUE || is_string($params['column_search']) === TRUE)) ? $params['column_search'] : [];

        // Set default order
        $this->order = (array_key_exists('order', $params) === TRUE && is_array($params['order']) === TRUE) ? $params['order'] : [];
    }

    /**
     * Fetch members data from the database
     * @param $postData
     * based on the posted parameters
     * @return
     */
    public function getRows($postData){
        $this->_get_datatables_query($postData);

        if(!empty($postData) && $postData['length'] != -1){
            $this->CI->db->limit($postData['length'], $postData['start']);
        }

        $query = $this->CI->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    /**
     * Count all records
     */
    public function countAll(){
        $this->CI->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->CI->db->count_all_results();
    }

    /**
     * Count records based on the filter params
     * @param $postData
     * filter data based on the posted parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function countFiltered($postData){
        $this->_get_datatables_query($postData);
        $query = $this->CI->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    /**
     * Perform the SQL queries needed for server-side processing requested
     * @param $postData
     * data|null based on the posted parameters
     */
    private function _get_datatables_query( $postData=null){

        $this->CI->db->from($this->table);


        $i = 0;
        // loop searchable columns
        foreach($this->column_search as $item){
            // if datatable send POST for search

            if(!empty($postData) && $postData['search']['value']){
                // first loop
                if($i===0){
                    // open bracket
                    $this->CI->db->group_start();

                    $this->CI->db->like($item, $postData['search']['value']);
                }else{
                    $this->CI->db->or_like($item, $postData['search']['value']);
                }

                // last loop
                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i){
                    // close bracket
                    $this->CI->db->group_end();
                }
            }

            $i++;
        }

//        //var_dump($this->where);
//        if($this->where){
//            foreach ($this->where as $key => $value){
//                $this->CI->db->group_start();
//
//                $this->CI->db->where($key ,$value);
//
//                $this->CI->db->group_end();
//
//                $i++;
//            }
//        }


        if(isset($postData['order']) && $postData['order'] !=''){
            $this->CI->db->order_by($this->column_order[$postData['order']['0']['column']], $postData['order']['0']['dir']);
        }else if(isset($this->order)){
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->CI->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller method Example :**

```
public function customer_json()
{
    
    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        exit('No direct script access allowed');
    }

    $data = array();

    //Load Library
    $this->load->library('serverside', array(
        'table' => 'ci_customer', //Db Table name
        'column_order' => array(null, 'id', 'firstname', 'age'),
        'column_search' => array('id', 'firstname', 'age'),
        'order' => array('id' => 'desc')
        //want to add where condition here
    ));

    // Fetch records server side
    $dbData = $this->serverside->getRows($_POST);

    $i = $_POST['start'] ?? '0';

    foreach ($dbData as $users) {
        $i++;

        $data[] = array(
            $i,
            $users->firstname,
            $users->age,
            '<a title="Edit" href="' . base_url('admin/user/customer?id=' . $users->id) . '" class="update btn btn-sm btn-warning-light" > <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>'
        );
    }

    $output = array(
        "draw" => $_POST['draw'] ?? '',
        "recordsTotal" => $this->serverside->countAll(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $this->serverside->countFiltered($_POST),
        "data" => $data,
    );

    // Output to JSON format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

**HTML Mark UP**

```
 <table id="DataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let table = $('#DataTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "aLengthMenu": [[15, 25, 50, 100 , -1], [ 15, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength" : 10,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "order": [],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo base_url('admin/users/customer_json'); ?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [simple demo implementation](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) provided by DataTables (see also [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html))? Look at the function on [line 173](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php#L173). And then look at lines 250 and 327 to see how it is used. That may give you some ideas.

Comment: Yes Thanks I have seen those and write this library from those code

Comment: Understood. Then maybe you can clarify the specific problem you are facing?